# How to display buffering sign /symbol during MpMovieplayer loading

Tags: ios, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

The issue i am getting is when a user click on a link to play a movie - I am using Mpmovie player to load the movie but it takes 5-10 seconds to show the movie  and during that time it shows a black page with nothing on it. Can I put a loading sign on it?

How can I use `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` to show buffering sign etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer you have to include this line

```
movieViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
```

otherwise it shows black screen